# What is equivalent of "toStartOf" and "toTopOf" in ConstraintSet?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

How is it possible to set correctly `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` and `layout_constraintTop_toTopOf` programmaticly?

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/firstButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/alarm"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />
```

So far, I can't find `toStartOf` and `toTopOf` properties of `ConstraintSet`, what is the equivalent of it?

```
    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(main_layout);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.firstButton, ConstraintSet.START,  R.id.guideline4, ConstraintSet.END);
    constraintSet.connect(R.id.firstButton, ConstraintSet.TOP,  R.id.guideline, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
    constraintSet.applyTo(main_layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if you want `start` to `start` and `top` to `top`, it is more like

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(main_layout);
constraintSet
  .connect(R.id.firstButton, ConstraintSet.START,  R.id.guideline4, ConstraintSet.START);
constraintSet
  .connect(R.id.firstButton, ConstraintSet.TOP,  R.id.guideline, ConstraintSet.TOP);
constraintSet.applyTo(main_layout);
```

?